# Need help creating a Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to validate:

- just numbers
- it have to start with the number 20
- the five number needs to be 0 or 1
- the seven number needs to be 1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@"^20\d{2}[0-1]\d[1-3]$"
```

Starts with 20, then 2 of any digits, then 0 or 1, then any digits, then 1, 2 or 3. If you need additional digits after the 7th, you can insert a `\d*` before the `$`:

```
@"^20\d{2}[0-1]\d[1-3]\d*$"
```

**Edit**: As CodeMonkey points out, `\d` will be interpreted in C# as an escape sequence, so be sure to use a verbatim string (as now shown above.)

Comment: It just doesn't need to end there ;)

Comment: +1 good work - works well. The only caveat is that the second sequence will match the target string and then some. So it probably isn't good for anyone to use that unless they know they are going to get some extra data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to validate a date `YYYYMMDD`?

Try this: http://programmerramblings.blogspot.com/2008/08/elegant-date-validation-in-c.html

Or this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/DateValCS02222009225005PM/DateValCS.aspx

Or this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
^20\d\d[01]\d[123]\d*$
```

Starts with 20, then 2 of any digits, then 0 or 1, then any digits, then 1, 2 or 3, then only digits or nothing.

Comment: The question is tagged C#, isn't your answer using javascript syntax?

Comment: No its using regexp syntax available for the most of programming languages and can be easily transformed.

Comment: Good to know.  There are so many regex engines I find it hard to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
^20\d{2}[01]\d[1-3]\d*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
20\d{2}[01]\d{1}[123]
```

Probably not very optimized, but it works :)

Comment: Nope, matches "aa20110512bf" for example

Answer (score 0):

```
20\d{2}(0|1)\d[1-3]
```

I think this will work

Comment: Nope, will match "aa20110512bf" as well for example

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C# I would recommend using the regular expression tester here http://regexhero.net/tester/  It is great, you will be able to see the results of you expression highlighted as you build your expression.